# OnBlur does not work on div

Tags: javascript

I have a div in a table `<td>`. When I add the onBlur event nothing happens. When I change the onBlur to a different event it works.

Does anyone know how I can add the onBlur to the div:

```
<div id="MyForm" onblur='Init()'>
```

Comment: [`FAQ`](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and [`How to ask`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) might be good reads for you in the New Year's Eve.

Comment: C# with classic ASP? How did you manage that? And how are either of these tags related to the question?

Comment: I suppose onBlur only works with input controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onblur` is ment for elements which had a focus, so typically inputs. A div can't be focussed, so it can't be blurred.

Did you mean `onmouseout`?

Comment: No I mean onBlur since in my div i have a table that holds <tr> which have a href to different pages, and i need that in thec case where this div was clicked no event should happen and only when an event was clicked out of this table then the function should be called...

Comment: Is there a way to add the onblur to the table itself?

Comment: no! you really need an element which can have a focus like `input, textarea, button, select ...`

Comment: href is only practicable on `<a>`

Comment: the tr includes a ahref in it:  <tr >
          <td  >
                                        <a  id="MM_temp" runat="server" style="width: 100%;" > <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="test"></asp:Label> </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

Comment: so the `blur` event is fired to the `<a>`, not to the `<tr>`!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, u mean i shall add the onBlur to the <a ?

Comment: nop did not help - is it because i have a label in it: <a onblur="alert('Cool');">  <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="notworking"></asp:Label> </a>

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions how I can solve these issue, what im trying to do is if someone clicked on any of the elements that are in the div- then nothing will happen , when there was a click out of the div then the function which hides the div will be executed. Thanks